# AndroidRuntime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: android, android-actionbar, noclassdeffounderror, android-appcompat

I have an android application which used external library (appcompat-v7) for action bar. My application starts from registration activity then to signin activity and after successful signin Dashboard activity is launched which has actionbar with tabs and swipes. Registration activity and signin activity works fine but when I click on Signin button application crashes with the error mention in title. I have addid the appcompat library to my work space and also added to my project as well. I have checked many solutions at SO but none of them worked for me. here are steps I have done.

```
Added appcompat to workspace as library project as mention on developer.android page. 
Added jar files of appcompat to build path of appcompat unchecked android dependencies.
Added appcompat library project to my project (say Project X)
Checked all library of project X, fix project properties, clean and rebuild.  
Moved android private libraries to top on order and Export tab.
added appcompatv7 to projects tab on Java build path.
Still no luck :(
My order and export tab looks like this from top to bottom
1-Android Private libraries 
2-Ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar (Jar file is located in D:\jarfiles)
3-android Dependencies 
4-/gen
5-/src
6-Android 4.4.2
```

Here is Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.appname.registration.Register" (only com.example.appname is replaced with original name of application when posted on SO)
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".registration.SignIn"></activity>
        <activity android:name="DashBoard"></activity>
    </application>
```

This is Sign in OnClick Event

```
Intent dashboardintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashBoard.class);
startActivity(dashboardintent);
finish();
```

[image]
[image]

Log Cat

```
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.appname.DashBoard
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.example.appname.registration.SignIn$1.onClick(SignIn.java:59)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-28 14:09:14.942: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 14:09:16.602: I/Process(658): Sending signal. PID: 658 SIG: 9
```

Comment: In your project properties, have you set appcompat7 as library?

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: @Mathew I have edited my question again. Please check log cat.

Answer (score 0):

[image] Check the library in `Order and Export` tab under `Java Build Path`

Answer (score 0):

Prefix dot in front of the class name in Manifest. If this class is in a specific package, then mention that in manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".DashBoard"></activity>
```

Please check whether this was the issue.

Comment: I have changed above line to 
com.example.packagename.DashBoard
Clean, fix project properties, rebuild. Its still same

Comment: Have you added Ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar inside your libs folder? 
Also are you using any other libraries that you have forgot to mention in manifest file?

Comment: Ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar is not under libs forlder but it is under Referenced Libries.
I have android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder

Comment: Can you add that in libs and then do a clean and refresh and see.

Comment: Still no luck. But I got another message on Console saying 
"Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!"

Comment: Remove appcompat from your order and export

Comment: message from console is gone but rest is still same class not found :(

Comment: No idea what is the issue then…probably seeing ur full project along with the library will may help...

Comment: Thanks for so much. I will try some other solution and post answer if issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete bin folder before run. I had this problem and delete the bin folder saved me